# Getting two different LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw a few examples but I did not understand it completely...

I have two tables: from table A I want to have a LIMIT 1 and from table B I want to have a LIMIT 5

```
SELECT A.`id` , A.`ip_adress` , A.`message_count` , B.`user_id` , 
B.`notice_id` , B.`subject` , B.`Description`
FROM `ip_register` LIMIT 1 
AS A INNER JOIN `user_shout` AS B
ON B.`user_id` = A.`id` 
WHERE ip_adress='$ip' AND NOT message_count='0' 
LIMIT 5
```

This SQL-code is an example that's not working correctly

I hope someone has a tip on how I get this working correctly

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause can be used only once and always goes at the end of the query. It is used to limit the set of records returned by the query. So, you cannot use it this way. We need some sample data along with expected result set in order to understand what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Giorgos Betsos, I`m not that known with SQL... Could you please give me a example in what way I can use it ???

Comment: If you don't provide any sampe data demonstrating the problem it will be really difficult to grasp what you are actually trying to echieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use subqueries and limit the results there:

```
SELECT A.`id`,
       A.`ip_adress`,
       A.`message_count`,
       B.`user_id`, 
       B.`notice_id`,
       B.`subject`,
       B.`Description`
       FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM `ip_register`
                    WHERE `ip_adress` = '$ip'
                          AND `message_count` <> '0'
                    LIMIT 1) A
            INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                               FROM`user_shout`
                               LIMIT 5) B
                       ON B.`user_id` = A.`id`;
```

Comment: Sticky Bit, Thanks for your support... I have in my database two results for testing, with your code I getting two buttons with two results... But I hoped to get one button with two results... It seems that the first LIMIT is not detecting & it only detect the LIMIT 5 for both tables... Is their another posibility ???

Comment: @Jan Molendijk: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean by "buttons with results"? As you didn't provide any sample data and the expected results, I cannot see the result and if it matches. Consider to provide more information on this for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Sticky Bit, sorry but my English is not optimal...
I used your code but in my Echo I getting two results separated

I have 2 examples standing in table B
from table A I expect to get only the message_count
with the 2 results from table B

```
   $sql = "
   SELECT A.`id`,
   A.`ip_adress`,
   A.`message_count`,
   B.`user_id`, 
   B.`notice_id`,
   B.`subject`,
   B.`Description`
   FROM (SELECT *
                FROM `ip_register`
                WHERE `ip_adress` = '$ip'
                      AND `message_count` <> '0'
               LIMIT 1  ) A
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT *
                           FROM`user_shout`
                           LIMIT 5) B
                   ON B.`user_id` = A.`id` ";
```

This is the echo-code

```
 echo '  
 <div class="dropdown">
 <div class="chip">
 <b>'. $row['message_count']. '</b> New
 </div>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  '. $row['subject']. '
 </div></div>' ;
```

[image: This result I getting]

This Result I getting
But I expect to get one button with two results

Comment: Instead of responding by posting an answer, please either add a comment or modify your original post. If you modify your original post, start the edit with a separator (e.g. horizontal rule) and/or header (e.g. **UPDATE:**) so that it's clear you are providing an update to the original question.